# Box2d fixture position

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

How to get position of every fixture of one body in Libgdx Box2d?
It seems like fixtures do not have position getter. Sory if this question is noobish but i just started learning Box2d.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your box2d body get the list of all fixtures.
For each fixture get its *shape*.
If the shape is of type CircleShape then you have a getPosition() method that you can use. However, the position retrieved is relative to the position of the box2d body in the b2World.

Comment: Does it have to be a CircleShape? In my case it is a PolygonShape and it doesn't have getPosition method.

Comment: why do you need the position of the fixture? There could be a workaround using the getVertex() method of the polygonshape.

Comment: So he can draw a sprite there. getVertex is really low level in comparison to a getPosition already provided on the higher level shapes.. A decent question on his part.

Comment: So does `body.setPosition()` set the body's position in the b2World? Also does the `getPosition()` method return the relative position of centerpoint of the shape or the top left position of the shape?

Answer (score 9):

This is easy once you know about `Transform`.

Let's take a circular fixture as an example, as they're the easiest to demonstrate with.

```
// we need to get the body's position, let's use a Vector2 to store it.
Vector2 vec = new Vector2();
Body body = fixture.getBody();

// what is this magic? Why, it's a wonderful object that transforms fixture
// position information based on the body's position!
Transform transform = body.getTransform();

CircleShape shape = (CircleShape) fixture.getShape();
vec.set(shape.getPosition());
// apply the transformation
transform.mul(vec);
// now vec.x and vec.y will be what you want!
```

Easy!

But what if you have a polygon instead of a circle? Easy again! Simply apply the transform to each vertex in the shape.

Comment: this would be nice... but PolygonShape for instance does not have a getPosition() method

Comment: Just to "beep" this one. Is there such a straightforward way for a polyshape (eg box)?

Comment: Turns out PolygonShape has a getVertex() method. I find the first vertex and multiple it by the body transform and everything lines up. I'm using setAsBox to configure the shape and a regular right-facing sprite for the graphical component.

Comment: remember that it is position in Box2d world, I was scratching my head for a bit because I forgot that and didn't scale from meters to pixels.